# Difference between Rs and INH Pin

Tags: integrated-circuit, can

I have this CANH CANL [transceiver](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/196/IFX1050GVIO_DS_10-1730780.pdf) which I unfortunately cannot order anymore. I've found these two ICs:

[1](https://docs.rs-online.com/75c7/0900766b814f3bfc.pdf#5)
[2](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20001667G-1115479.pdf)

The pins match with the original IC except for one pin.
On the original IC it's called INH pin and on the new ICs it is Rs.

Is this the same pin and can I use one of the replacements?

Answer (score 0):

The MCP2551 will be no different from IFX1050, assuming the 8th pin of the IC is tied to ground when actively using the CAN bus.
Well, IFX1050 is a perfect copy of NXP's TJA1050, or the other way around. And, by the way, virtually all 8-pin CAN bus transceivers share the same pinout and the same pin functions, except the 8th pin, but if this pin is externally pulled low, it will always work regardless of the manufacturer or chip id.

P.S.
Both links redirect to the same MCP2551

Comment: Pin 5 and 8 can both be different. Some use pin 5 for Vio, some use it for slope control, some use it for split termination etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace this with a modern transceiver like [MCP2562FD](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp2562fd) as "drop-in" replacement. At a glance they both seem to have similar functions at pin 5 (V<sub>IO</sub>) and pin 8 (sleep mode). Just make sure to use the SO-8 part.

These are also still somewhat available from vendors despite the current component shortage.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but unfortunately this transceiver isn't available anymore.

Comment: @torlll No idea how you came to that conclusion. It's in stock at RS Components among others.